# Is there an analogue to Object.defineProperty to define variables?

Tags: javascript

It's easy to make private variables accessed by public methods of a module you're exporting:

```
var makeAModule = function() {
    var _secret = 'Ssh!';
    var module = {
        tellMeYourSecret: function() {
            console.log(_secret);
        }
    };
    return module;
}

//  > var m = makeAModule();
//  > m.tellMeYourSecret();
//  Ssh!
```

Sometimes I need to define properties with Object.defineProperty that are computed by getters using the value of other private variables.  Those have to go on an object, though, so I end up making a private object just to hold them.  If I don't store all my private members on that object, it gets confusing to remember which props are on it and which aren't, so I put everything there:

```
var makeAModule = function() {
    var priv = {};
    priv._secret = 'Ssh!';
    Object.defineProperty(priv, 'secretLength', {
        get: function() { 
            return priv._secret.length; 
        }
    });
    var module = {
        tellMeYourSecret: function() {
            console.log(priv._secret);
        },
        howLongIsYourSecret: function() {
            console.log(priv._secretLength);
        }
    }
    return module;
}

//  > var m = makeAModule();
//  > m.howLongIsYourSecret();
//  4
```

Is there any way to define a variable (not attached to an object) whose value is computed through a getter?  Something like this:

```
var makeAModule = function() {
    var _secret = 'Ssh!';
    Object.defineVariable('_secretLength', {
        get: function() {
            return _secret.length;
        }
    })

    var module = {
        tellMeYourSecret: function() {
            console.log(_secret);
        },
        howLongIsYourSecret: function() {
            console.log(_secretLength);
        }
    }
    return module;
}
```

Comment: No, there is not. You can mock this but only indirectly  (eg. `myvariables.foo = ..` or as explicit `setter(value)/getter()`).

Comment: you can overload .valueOf() and or toString() to make custom getters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly.

However, you can set it as a property of `window`, thus making it a global variable. But using global variables is not recommendable, specially if they are secret.

```js
var makeAModule = function() {
  var priv = {};
  priv._secret = 'Ssh!';
  Object.defineProperty(window, '_secretLength', {
    get: function() { 
      return priv._secret.length; 
    }
  });
  return {
    tellMeYourSecret: function() {
      return _secret;
    },
    howLongIsYourSecret: function() {
      return _secretLength;
    }
  };
};
document.body.innerHTML =
  "Secret length: " + makeAModule().howLongIsYourSecret();
```

Alternatively, you can define your getters as properties of an object, and use a [`with` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.10). Note that the `with` statement can't be used in strict mode.

```js
var makeAModule = function() {
  var priv = {};
  priv._secret = 'Ssh!';
  Object.defineProperty(priv, '_secretLength', {
    get: function() { 
      return priv._secret.length; 
    }
  });
  with(priv) {
    return {
      tellMeYourSecret: function() {
        return _secret;
      },
      howLongIsYourSecret: function() {
        return _secretLength;
      }
    };
  }
};
document.body.innerHTML =
  "Secret length: " + makeAModule().howLongIsYourSecret();
```